# Groove Music reloads song and loses position after suspend

Tags: windows-10, groove-music

Running Windows 10, build 1607.

I can play a song with Groove Music, close the app, reopen it, song resumes after I press Play.

I can play a song with Groove Music, shut down the computer, turn it back on, reopen Groove Music, and the song resumes after I press Play.

But when I suspend the computer, and it turns back on, Groove Music shows the song and has  the correct position, but pressing Play shows a loading icon on the album image in the bottom left, and then the song starts playing **from the beginning**, not where I was.

Is this a bug that was fixed in a later update? I can't do updates right now so I hope it is just a simple fix.

BTW these are MP3 files.

Comment: Really? No solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after installing the Creators Update, the problem seemed to have fixed itself. Not sure what it originally was though.